# how to set variable value fixed for first time and second time it does not change in php?

Tags: php, yii

This is my Controller:

```
public function actionCreate1(){
$model = new Model();
//blah blah blah blah
return $this->actionCreate2($model);
}

public function actionCreate2($model = null)
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $model = $_POST['model'];
        print_r($model); //Returns not adjuct same object
        }
    $this->renderPartial('create2', array('model' => $model));
}
```

and view is:

```
<form method="post" action="/create2" id="space-create2-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="model" value="<?php print_r($model); ?>"/></div>
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

As i call `actionCreate1` in the end i return to `actionCreate2` with object of `model` . First time when it call `actionCreate2` i got perfect value of `model`. But when i call `actionCreate2` after posting value through view part, then i got different object. How can i set `$model` value fixed in `actionCreate2` for first time, so that it can not change when i come back through POST. Or any another way so that i can get same object of `$model` in `actionCreate2` as it is in `actionCreate1`

Answer (score 0):

Try by declaring it as 'Static'

EX:
static $model

Comment: Hi Sagar,  I declare static $model in `actionCreate2` but that not working .